# Цикличное выполнение функции JS (какой цикл использовать)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Вывожу список кастомных постов WordPress:

```
<?php
$mfoArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'mfo',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => '',
    'order' => ''
);
$mfo = new WP_Query($mfoArgs); ?>
<?php if ($mfo->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ($mfo->have_posts()): $mfo->the_post() ?>
        <?php if(!empty(get_field('first_loan_free')) && get_field('first_loan_precent') >= 0){
            $precentForCalculated = get_field('first_loan_precent');
            $display = "block";
        }else{
            $precentForCalculated = get_field('standart_precent_loan');
            $display = "none";
        }?>
        <div class="loan-precent" data-precent="<?php echo $precentForCalculated ?>"></div>
        <div class="mfo-item">
            <div class="column small-12 medium-3">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <img class="mfo-item__thumb" src="<?php the_field('logo_mfo') ?>"
                         alt="<?php the_title() ?>">
                </a>
                <div class="mfo-item__rating text-center">
                    <?php echo kk_star_ratings(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.column small-12 medium-3 -->
            <div class="column small-12 medium-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
                        <p class="mfo-item__subtitle">
                            <?php _e('Тело кредита') ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mfo-item__value">
                        <div class="loan-summ"></div> <?php the_field('valute_site', 'options') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.column small-12 medium-4 -->
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
                        <p class="mfo-item__subtitle">
                            <?php _e('Комиссия') ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mfo-item__value">
                            <div class="total-precent"></div> <?php the_field('valute_site', 'options') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.column small-12 medium-4 -->
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
                        <p class="mfo-item__subtitle">
                            <?php _e('К возврату') ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mfo-item__value">
                        <div class="money-total"></div> <?php the_field('valute_site', 'options') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.column small-12 medium-4 -->
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
                        <p class="mfo-item__subtitle">
                            <?php _e('1-й кредит') ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mfo-item__value">
                            <?php the_field('min_summ_loan')?> - <?php the_field('max_summ_first_loan') ?> <?php the_field('valute_site', 'options') ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.column small-12 medium-4 -->
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
                        <p class="mfo-item__subtitle">
                            <?php _e('Повторный') ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mfo-item__value">
                            <?php the_field('max_summ_next_loan') ?> <?php the_field('valute_site', 'options') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.column small-12 medium-4 -->
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
                        <p class="mfo-item__subtitle">
                            <?php _e('Срок') ?>
                        </p>
                        <p class="mfo-item__value">
                            <?php the_field('min_time_loan')?> - <?php the_field('max_time_loan') ?> <?php _e('дней') ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.column small-12 medium-4 -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.column small-12 medium-6 -->
            <div class="column small-12 medium-3"></div>
            <!-- /.column small-12 medium-3 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Как выполнить приведенную ниже функцию столько раз, сколько будет выведено кастомных постов. При этом, что бы переменная `$loanPrecent`, которая в JS передается через дата атрибут `data-precent="<?php echo $precentForCalculated ?>"`, использовала значение присвоенное именно этому посту.
Через php `<?php echo $precentForCalculated ?>` для каждого выведенного в списке поста тянет свое значение из б.д., а вот js подхватывает первое и использует его для всех остальных.

Вот сама функция, которую, наверное, нужно использовать циклично, но какой цикл использовать и как?

```
$(function () {
    var $loanPrecent = $('.loan-precent').data('precent') // процент за пользование кредитом
    var $loanTerm = $('.loan-term')
    var $loanSumm = $('.loan-summ')
    var $fullBack = $('.money-total')
    var $total = $(".total-precent"),
        a = 0,
        b = 0

    function sum() {
        var total = (a * $loanPrecent / 100) * b;
        var fullBack = total + a;
        var loanSumm = a;
        var loanTerm = b;
        $total.text(total.toFixed(2));
        $fullBack.text(fullBack.toFixed(2));
        $loanSumm.text(loanSumm);
        $loanTerm.text(loanTerm);
    }

    $("#summ-loan").ionRangeSlider({
        skin: "big",
        grid_num: "3",
        onStart: function (data) {
            a = data.from;
            sum();
        },
        onChange: function (data) {
            a = data.from;
            sum();
        }
    });

    $("#day").ionRangeSlider({
        skin: "big",
        grid_num: "3",
        onStart: function (data) {
            b = data.from;
            sum();
        },
        onChange: function (data) {
            b = data.from;
            sum();
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать цикл.

Comment: Та я б с удовольствием, но не знаю какой и как))

Comment: Выделить для одного поста отдельный css класс, и в js выяснить сколько данных классов есть, и столько раз выполнить цикл...думаю `forEach` вам поможет

Comment: так уже пробовал. получается, что php цикл выводит несколько идентичных по структуре (классы, id элементов и т.д.) постов (карточки финансовых компаний), например, 5. в них 5 раз повторяется элемент с дата атрибутом, который передает значение в js (процент за пользование кредитом у каждой отдельной компании). js считает формулу и в нужном месте выводиться результат расчетов.

Comment: Для каждого поста значение в дата атрибут из б.д. передается разное, но js хватает только первое и когда запускается js цикл, он не перебирает отдельно значения по дата атрибуту, которое вывел php для каждой финкомпании, а считает все с использованием первого, которое зашло в переменную и результат расчета для всех компаний получается одинаковый.

Получается, что в каждую новую итерацию нужно вытягивать новое значение с последующего поста. Если да, то как это сделать? Или х.з...

http://prntscr.com/qjattb